# Barcode scanner enters data on google form

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, google-forms

I have a google form with 1 text question
And DATALOGIC QuickScan Device..

I need to use the barcode scanner device to scan a barcode, which enters the scanned data in the text field.

Additionally, if it is applicable, can it submit the form directly after scanning the barcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program the scanner to send a carriage return after the scan data, then it works.

Comment: can you tell me how because i have never programmed a scanner before?

Comment: The quick installation guide of the scanner has configuration barcodes for this purpose.  Just scan them in.  You can find the quick install guide online, but you must print it out, as a laser scanner can not read from a screen.